# Can using the HREF with jQuery be vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

[Burp suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) showing error.

> The application may be vulnerable to DOM-based cross-site scripting. Data is read from location and passed to jQuery() via the following statement:
>   here location is javascript location object containing current address hash
>       jQuery(location).attr('href').split("//")[1];
>   is the above code vulnerable to cross site scripting?

It is used in the following code

```
var address = jQuery(location).attr('href').split('//')[1]; 
subdomain = address.split('.')[0]; 
this.href = this.href.replace(subdomain, 'www'); 
window.location = this.href;
```

Comment: It's this part that's the issue: `jQuery(location)`. What is `location` and where does it come from?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My guess would be `window.location`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes jQuery(location) is the part showing error. location is a javascript location object containing location hash(current url)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a *false positive* error. Others have had similar expierences.

A person from the Burp suite Support Center said the following:

> The code is very close to being exploitable. If it was:
>
> `$(location).attr(‘href’, ‘’ + var1 + ’/’);`
>
> And var1 could be controlled by an attacker, they could inject “javascript:alert(document.domain)” and that would be executed. However, prepending the slash will prevent this.
>
> Our static analysis is likely to produce false positives on similar patterns, as we don’t attempt to do string analysis.

[Page of thread above](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/questions/17261597-cross-site-scripting-dom-based-)

So as long as you don't allow variables into your `href` attribute then you'll be fine. In this case you only seem to *read* the `href` attribute value.

Comment: Here, what should be possible solution ?